# change cell properties from an excel file open with a wsf script

Tags: vba, csv, excel, vbscript

i have a wsf script, vritten in visual basic, that run a db2 query and save the results in a file .csv .

```
Function CreaCSVdaSQL (SQL,fileCompletePath)

  Dim Input , conn,rs,csvtext,fso,fs,line
  set conn = CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection") 
  conn.open _ 
  "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Data Source=XXXXX;MARS Connection=True;User Id=XXXX;password=XXXX"

  set rs = conn.execute (SQL) 
  line = ""
  Dim tmp
  For Each tmp In rs.Fields
      line=line & tmp.Name & ";"
  Next

  if (Not rs.EOF) then

      csvText = line & vbcrlf & rs.getString (2,, ";", VBCrLf) 
      rs.close: set rs = nothing 
      conn.close: set conn = nothing 

      Dim l_sn 
      l_sn = Replace (Now, "-", "") 
      l_sn = Replace (l_sn, ":", "") 
      l_sn = Replace (l_sn, "", "") 

      set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
      set fs = fso.CreateTextFile (fileCompletePath, true) 
      fs.writeline (csvText) 
      fs.close: set fs = nothing 
      set fso = nothing 

  end if

End Function
```

Everytime my collegue open the file csv with excel have to change the cell in text format, i try to find a way to do it programmatically, without a macro, because the file is deleted everytime the script run and cannot store the macro.

Somebody can help me ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A .CSV file can't store data type/meta info about columns. If db2 does not provide tools to export to .XLS directly/reliably, your options are:

1. Create a [schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms709353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) file to describe the structure of your .CSV
2. Use the Import dialog wizard to create and save a suitable import specification; then open the .CSV via a macro refering to this specs
3. Enhance your SQL query by concatenating with quotes or re-formatting where appropriate
4. Open the .CVS using "Excel.Application", do the necessary changes, save as .XLS